# Copy Photo from iPod to MacBook using Apple Software

Tags: macos, photos, ipod, iphoto

I'm trying to pull a photo off my iPod. The iPod is connected to my MacBook. I don't usually use photos, so I'm struggling.

The iPod is showing up under iTunes, but there's no "Photo" category. So I can't simply drag/drop to the MacBook through iTunes (that would apparently be way to easy on users).

Under iPhotos, there is nothing that appears to be related to the iPod for importing photos:

[image]

Trying to click on "Connect a camera or memory card" does nothing because its not a link.

Under Image Capture, there is a "Devices" category, but my iPod does not show up:

[image]

What Apple program am I supposed to be using to get photos off my iPod? Or how do I use one of the programs above to do it?

Unplugging/re-plugging the iPod in does not help. And closing iTunes and opening iTunes does not help. I've also rebooted the MacBook and the iPod.

Or is this a case of more broken and untested software coming out of Cupertino? (I can't count how many hours I have wasted on their other products while trying to figure out how things work and why they don't work as expected. I don't even bother filing RADARs anymore because nothing seems to gets fixed).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what iPod you have. Please give this info next time. Make sure your iPod touch (I hope it's a touch because that would be the problem if it wasn't) is plugged in firmly to the USB slot on your MacBook. Try removing the cord and plugging it into a different slot. Make sure the device is powered on. Also, you should upgrade your computer to OSX Mavericks (10.9), because it is free, Apple expects you to update, and may not support old OSX Versions with new software on iPod touch, so I would also update.
If the problem persists see an Apple Store.

> Or is this a case of more broken and untested software coming out of Cupertino? (I can't count how many hours I have wasted on their other products while trying to figure out how things work and why they don't work as expected.

As for that, please try and either call support or fix it before you make a rude comment like that because it may be your fault and you never know. :)
It would also help if we knew what year MacBook and iPod touch version you have. Get the newest, and try again. If it is a singular photo, email or message it to yourself. Hoped that helped! Have a nice day.